# Regex of number between ::tags::

Tags: regex

I have a series of records with the following pattern:

```
::cck::1::/cck::
::cck::34::/cck::
::cck::268::/cck::
::cck::1341::/cck::
::cck::54345::/cck::
```

I'd like to create a regular expression to match all records like there:

::cck:: some numbers ::/cck::

Any suggestions?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it.

```
::cck::[0-9]*::/cck::
```

`[0-9]*` matches all the characters 0 to 9, with one or more occurrance.

Answer (score 2):

If your file is that format then it's easier to use [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)

```
cut -d':' -f5 inputfile
1
34
268
1341
54345
```